# Randomly select timeframes as tuples from a list of time points

Tags: python, list, random, tuples, probability

I have several time points taken from a video with some max time length (`T`).  These points are stored in a list of lists as follows:

```
time_pt_nested_list = 
[[0.0, 6.131, 32.892, 43.424, 46.969, 108.493, 142.69, 197.025, 205.793, 244.582, 248.913, 251.518, 258.798, 264.021, 330.02, 428.965],
 [11.066, 35.73, 64.784, 151.31, 289.03, 306.285, 328.7, 408.274, 413.64],
 [48.447, 229.74, 293.19, 333.343, 404.194, 418.575],
 [66.37, 242.16, 356.96, 424.967],
 [78.711, 358.789, 403.346],
 [84.454, 373.593, 422.384],
 [102.734, 394.58],
 [158.534],
 [210.112],
 [247.61],
 [340.02],
 [365.146],
 [372.153]]
```

Each list above is associated with some probability; I'd like to randomly select points from each list according to its probability to form `n` tuples of contiguous time spans, such as the following:

```
[(0,t1),(t1,t2),(t2,t3),...,(tn,T)]
```

where `n` is specified by the user.  All the returned tuples should only contain the floating point numbers inside the nested list above. I want to assign the highest probability to them to be sampled and appear in the returned tuples, the second list a slightly lower probability, etc. The exact details of these probabilities are not important, but it would be nice if the user can input a parameter that controls how fast the probability decays when `idx` increases.

The returned tuples are timeframes that should exactly cover the entire video and should not overlap. `0` and `T` may not necessarily appear in `time_pt_nested_list` (but they may). Are there nice ways to implement this? I would be grateful for any insightful suggestions.

For example if the user inputs 6 as the number of subclips, then this will be an example output:

```
[(0.0, 32.892), (32.892, 64.784), (64.784, 229.74), (229.74, 306.285), (306.285, 418.575), (418.575, 437.47)]
```

All numbers appearing in the tuples appeared in `time_pt_nested_list`, except `0.0` and `437.47`. (Well `0.0` does appear here but may not in other cases) Here `437.47` is the length of video which is also given and may not appear in the list.

Comment: can you provide an example of expected output?

Comment: Yes, please see the edited post.

Comment: Because I want to make it more likely for the numbers in the first sublist to appear in the returned tuples, than the numbers in the other sublists - in other words, elements in `time_pt_nested_list[idx]` should appear in the returned tuples more often for small `idx` and less often for larger `idx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simpler than it may look.  You really just need to sample `n` points from your sublists, each with row-dependent sample probability.  Whatever samples are obtained can be time-ordered to construct your tuples.

```
import numpy as np

# user params
n = 6
prob_falloff_param = 0.2

lin_list = sorted([(idx, el) for idx, row in enumerate(time_pt_nested_list) for 
el in row], key=lambda x: x[1])

# endpoints required, excluded from random selection process
t0 = lin_list.pop(0)[1]
T = lin_list.pop(-1)[1]
arr = np.array(lin_list)

# define row weights, alpha is parameter
weights =  np.exp(-prob_falloff_param*arr[:,0]**2)
norm_weights = weights/np.sum(weights)

# choose (weighted) random points, create tuple list:
random_points = sorted(np.random.choice(arr[:,1], size=(n-1), replace=False))

time_arr = [t0, *random_points, T]
output = list(zip(time_arr, time_arr[1:]))
```

example outputs:

```
# n = 6 
[(0.0, 78.711),
 (78.711, 84.454),
 (84.454, 158.534),
 (158.534, 210.112),
 (210.112, 372.153),
 (372.153, 428.965)]

# n = 12
[(0.0, 6.131),
 (6.131, 43.424),
 (43.424, 64.784),
 (64.784, 84.454),
 (84.454, 102.734),
 (102.734, 210.112),
 (210.112, 229.74),
 (229.74, 244.582),
 (244.582, 264.021),
 (264.021, 372.153),
 (372.153, 424.967),
 (424.967, 428.965)]
```